# Laravel 5.1 & Typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.1, typeahead.js

js setup in Laravel 5.1 project doesn't work.
I can't understand how i can pass my input text so i can compare the texts.

Here is my Controller:

```
public function getStudentDataTutorschool(){

    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user_id = $user->getTutorschoolId(Auth::user()->id);

        $tutorschool = Tutorschool::find($user_id)->first();

        $student_ids = array();

        $students = array();

        $results = array();

        $finals = array();

        $queries = DB::table('student_tutorschool')
            ->select('student_id')
            ->where('tutorschool_id', '=', $tutorschool->user_id)
            ->get();

        //Adds in the student_ids the USER_ID
        foreach ($queries as $query) {
            $student_ids[] = ['id' => $query->student_id];
        }

        //Αdds in the $students array the id of student
        foreach ($student_ids as $student_id) {

            $user = User::find($student_id)->first();

            $studentdatas = $user->students;

            foreach ($studentdatas as $studentdata) {
                $students[] = ['id' => $studentdata->id];
            }
        }
        $get = Input::get('search');

        foreach ($students as $student) {
            $thestudent = Student::find($student)->first();
            $results[] = ['name' => $thestudent->name, 'surname' => $thestudent->surname, 'user_id' => $thestudent->user_id];

        }
        return response()->json($results);

    }else{
        return redirect('403');
    }
}
```

Here is my Form:

```
<form method="get">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input name="search"  class="scholio-input typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Μαθητές">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my Root:

```
Route::get('tutorchool/getstudentdatadashboardsearch','SearchController@getStudentDataTutorschool');
```

Here is my localhost/tutorchool/getstudentdatadashboardsearch link return

[image]

Comment: What's your typeahead setup look like? (Also your route should have a param variable in it, `tutorchool/getstudentdatadashboardsearch/{query}`)

Comment: why i must have a variable what's the use of it?

Comment: If you don't supply the value from the input, how are you going to compare it to something in your controller?